# why run sbt with " ./ " prefix? it doesn't work

Tags: java, scala, sbt, apache-kafka

I'm trying to install Kafka and the docs says to do:

```
> tar xzf kafka-<VERSION>.tgz
> cd kafka-<VERSION>
> ./sbt update
> ./sbt package
> ./sbt assembly-package-dependency
```

So, when I try to run `./sbt update` I get this error:

```
root@kfk1:~/kafka-0.8.1.1-src# ./sbt
-bash: ./sbt: No such file or directory
```

But if I try without " ./ ", it seems to work:

```
root@kfk1:~/kafka-0.8.1.1-src# sbt update
Getting org.scala-sbt sbt 0.13.5 ...
```

- Use this prefix is a must? Why?
- If I don't use, the executed command is the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check that the file sbt exists and has execute permissions.

./ means to look in the current directory for the script.

. == current directory
.. == parent directory

Comment: the file doesn't exists in the dir. maybe this is an issue with downloaded kafka?

Comment: possibly ... or their documentation is incorrect?  Without the ./, it's executing the command it's finding on your system path (the $PATH variable on linux)

Comment: I'm checking this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

By the way, Kafka 0.8.1.1 use gradle, and not sbt.
That's why you don't have the sbt file in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

no need to ./sbt anymore
all kafka's jar files are in the lib folder